# Resizing images for training in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to read my own images for training in TensorFlow. However, there seems to be an error:

```
ValueError: 'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width.
```

What is wrong with the following code sample?

```
filenames=['images/000001.jpg','images/000002.jpg','images/000003.jpg','images/000004.jpg']
labels=[1,0,1,0]

filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

reader=tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
images=tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
images=tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
resized_images=tf.image.resize_images(images, 224, 224)

image_batch, label_batch=tf.train.batch([resized_images, labels], batch_size=2)
```

Comment: what is the error? please provide it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error says, `size` must be a 1-D Tensor. What tensorflow actually means with this is just to make the second argument of `tf.image.resize_images` a tuple:

```
resized_images = tf.image.resize_images(images, (224, 224))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and make the tuple a TensorFlow constant

```py
resized_images = tf.image.resize(images, tf.constant([224, 224]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resized_image = tf.image.resize(images, [224, 224])
```

The error message you encountered indicates that the size argument for resizing should be a 1-D tensor with two elements

```
'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width
```